# ExtensionInstallForcelist keep blocking a local Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i am trying to force the installation of a local extension trough registry, once i configure the registry files chrome show me the Words [BLOCKED] (see screenshot).

i made a Reg file to configure this and in some computers is working well but other ones are blocking it.

**i have changed some Ids and hide some information for sercurity.**

i have configured this three policies to install it:

- ExtensionInstallForcelist - "ikgllpfbenaieoppkxxxhokonmnnhjcl;file:///C:/CRX/updates.xml"
- ExtensionInstallSources - "file///C:/CRX/*"
- ExtensionInstallWhitelist - "ikgllpfbenaieoppkxxxhokonmnnhjcl"

i have tried the next but it still not working:

**- i have validated the Id's in all the policies a lot of times and are equal, and remember that it is working on some computers but others not.**

- BlockExternalExtensions - Disabled
- EnableOnlineRevocationChecks - Disabled
- ExtensionAllowedTypes - all types allowed
- ExtensionInstallBlacklist - "*" (to only allow the whitelisted extensions).
- Even modify manually those through the Gpedit.msc

this is the screenshot of the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6xT1.jpg)

this is the updates.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
  <app appid='ikgllpfbenaieoppkxxxhokonmnnhjcl'>
    <updatecheck codebase='file:///C:/CRX/XXXXXXX.crx' version='11.0' />
  </app>
</gupdate>
```

Comment: did you get any solution

Answer (score 1):

Your computer must join domain or managed by mdm in order to make the policy work.

You can add some fake registry to make win10 think your computer is managed by mdm.

Fake mdm guide: https://hitco.at/blog/apply-edge-policies-for-non-domain-joined-devices/

Only the first script (MDM-FakeEnrollment-Win10.reg) is needed to make the policy work.