# ExtensionInstallForcelist with locally stored extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, registry

Values in **___\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist**
registry now can not be used to automatically install locally stored extensions? Extensions that can be acquired from google webstore work flawlessly and can be automatically installed just fine.

Can I specify a value like: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa;file:///__path_to_update_manifest_xml.xml` and in the specified path I have an xml file like :

```
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='1.0'>
    <app appid='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'>
      <updatecheck codebase='file:\\\path\to\extension\file.crx' version='2.0'/>
    </app>
</gupdate>
```

which points to my .crx extension file? Would this approach work if I want a locally stored extension to be automatically installed and irremovable? I've tried this approach but it didn't work, maybe I've made a mistake somewhere, or is automatically installing locally stored extension even possible anymore? I know non-google webstore extensions are no longer allowed (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/autoupdate/) but is this also the case for local extensions as well?

Resources looked at:
[ExtensionInstallForcelist keep blocking a local Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61825798/extensioninstallforcelist-keep-blocking-a-local-extension)
https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ExtensionInstallForcelist

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I was trying to do nearly the same thing. Also hosting the .crx and the .xml on a web server does not result in an installation. Unfortunately, I was not able to find any official statement or something like this from Google which confirms that it is no longer possible to install extensions on Windows / macOS from outside the Chrome Store. Only thing I could find was the comment to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381471/self-hosting-chrome-extension